# How to skip assembly signing at Travis CI build on github?

Tags: c#, github, code-signing, travis-ci

I added Travis CI to one of my github projects. The .yml file looks like this -

```
language: csharp
solution: src/MySolution.sln
install: 
- nuget restore src/MySolution.sln
```

The Travis build fails with error -

```
Error during assembly signing. The specified key file `MySolutionKey.pfx' does not exist
```

I can't publish the key file used for assembly signing to github. So, is there a way to skip the signing process at Travis so the build completes successfully?

Comment: Generate another key file and use that in Travis by copying it to the expected path before building.

Comment: That's one option. I can also push a version without assembly signing. But what I am looking for is any xbuild directive in .yml file so I don't need to maintain multiple copies.